Clarification on the definition of "birational map" in Zariski's Main Theorem
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two schemes. When one says that $f:X\to Y$ is a birational map, I suppose there are two possibilities :

$f:X\to Y$ is a morphism, and there exists $U\subseteq X$ (resp. $V\subseteq Y$) open dense subsets such that the restriction of $f$ induces an isomorphism $U\to V$.
There exists $U\subseteq X$ (resp. $V\subseteq Y$) open dense subsets, and an isomorphism $U\to V$. But the map $f$ need not be defined everywhere on $X$.

Now, my question is, which definition of a birational map is used when discussing Zariski's Main Theorem, particularly the version stated here: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a quasi-finite separated birational map of varieties, where $Y$ is normal. Then $f$ is an open immersion (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78696/is-there-an-intuitive-reason-for-zariskis-main-theorem) ?
If we use definition 2, what does it mean to say that a birational map is quasi-finite (or separated, or satisfies other properties), given that the map is not necessarily defined everywhere? Are these two definitions after all equivalent in some contexts?
I'm confused by the terminology and struggle to understand the use of "birational map" each time it appears in different contexts. I would appreciate if someone could help clarify the precise meaning of it.

Nowadays the first will be called a birational morphism. Zariski main theorem has a birational morphism.

@Mohan Thank you for the answer! Do you know if there's a version of Zariski's Main Theorem that allows us to extend a birational map in definition 2?
